# All fields recognised as String when importing CSV with CSVT in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, csv, import

I am trying to import data contained in a CSV file `Chomage 1975.csv`, with a CSVT file `Chomage 1975.csvt` in the same folder.

My CSV file content is:

```
Code;City Name;Unemployment rate 15 years and over 1975
01001;L'Abergement-Clémenciat;0
01002;L'Abergement-de-Varey;0
```

and my CSVT file content is:

```
"String";"String";"Real"
```

However, I keep getting this as field formats:

[image]

I have tried importing it as a delimited text layer, as a vector layer, and just dragging it but I keep getting the same result.

I am using QGIS 3.20.3 on Windows 10.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What if you try this `"String(5)","String(30)","Real(4.2)"` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use commas instead of semi-colons in your .csvt file

```
"String","String","Real"
```

You can see the documentation for the .csvt file syntax [here](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/supported_data.html#csvt-files)